# The pointer in signal_connect function is not working correct

Tags: c, pointers, gtk3, gtkmm

I want to use the `g_signal_connect()` function to change data in a specific `struct/class`. So, in my opinion, the best way is to use a pointer to the `struct`. the problem is that the information of the pointer seems to be changing all the time.

I spent a lot of time to figure out why is that happening, but I have no idea.
I can compile and run the code without any error but the output is always different.

Later I want to use several event_box to connect to an array of struct or an array of a class (`event_box[0]` connect to `data[0]`,...).

I hope someone understands what I mean and I would be happy about any help.

```
#include<gtk/gtk.h>

struct d
{
bool status;
int ID;
};

void end_program(GtkWidget *wid, gpointer ptr)
{
gtk_main_quit();
}

void box_click(GtkWidget *wid, gpointer user_data)
{
    struct d *data = (struct d*)user_data;
    printf("status  = %i\n", data->status);
    printf("ID      = %i\n", data->ID);
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct d data;
    data.status = 0;
    data.ID = 1;

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    GtkWidget *win = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);

    GtkWidget *event_box  = gtk_event_box_new();
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(event_box), "button_press_event", G_CALLBACK(box_click), &data); 

    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(win), event_box);
    gtk_widget_show_all(win);
    g_signal_connect(win, "delete_event", G_CALLBACK(end_program),NULL);

    gtk_main();

    return 0;
}
```

Output if I click the box several times:

```
status  = 4
ID      = 32193184
status  = 5
ID      = 32193184
status  = 4
ID      = 32193184
status  = 6
ID      = 32193184
status  = 4
ID      = 32193184
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I hope someone understands what I mean and I would be happy about any
>   help.

Well, yes.. You are using the wrong function prototype for a `button-press-event`. The prototype for a `button-press-event` is:

```
The “button-press-event” signal

gboolean
user_function (GtkWidget *widget,
               GdkEvent  *event,
               gpointer   user_data)
```

(**note:** the signal is properly `"button-press-event"` instead of `"button_press_event"`, though there is a `#define` allowing the second form to work)

See [GtkWidget (Gtk+3 Manual)](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#GtkWidget-button-press-event). So what your function should look like is:

```
gboolean box_click(GtkWidget *wid, GdkEvent *event, gpointer user_data)
{
    struct d *data = user_data;            /* no need for cast, gpointer is void* */
    g_print("status  = %d\n", data->status);
    g_print("ID      = %d\n", data->ID);

    return TRUE;    /* to prevent further handling, FALSE otherwise */

    (void)wid;      /* cast to void to avoid unused var warning */
    (void)event;
}
```

*Additional Nits*

Use `g_print` instead of `printf`, use `gboolean` instead of `bool`. While passing the `address of` is fine for small structs, for large structs you should allocate with `g_slice_new`.

Comment: Thank you! That works very well for me so far. I just don't understand why I have to use `struct d *data = (struct d*)user_data` instead of `struct d *data = user_data`.  If I try to use it without `(struct d*)` than I get this error:

`main_.cpp: In function ‘gboolean box_click(GtkWidget*, GdkEvent*, gpointer)’:
main_.cpp:16:22: error: invalid conversion from ‘gpointer {aka void*}’ to ‘d*’ [-fpermissive]
     struct d *data = user_data;`

Comment: Oh, If you are compiling with C++, then yes you need the `(struct d*)` cast. Gtk is normally compiled with C, gtkmm is C++. (that also explains why you got away with `bool` instead of `gboolean`). Who told you to use `.cpp` for Gtk?

Comment: Okay I understand. Nobody told me to use .cpp I just use it because before I start with gtk I always write my programs in C++. I started learning gtk by myself around 2 months ago. So I guess it's better to use C code instead to learn how to use C++ with gtk? I think C should be enough for my applications.

Comment: Yes, I would encourage C for Gtk+, that is what it was designed for. I built your code with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -o evboxstruct evboxstruct.c \`pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0\``

Comment: Okay thank you. Before I use `gtkmm-3.0` because I read it somewhere. Now I changed my whole program to C and compiled it with `gtk+-3.0`. I was a little bit confused about this so thank you for your explanation.

Comment: Sure, if you want to dot all the I's and cross all the T's I would add `-pedantic -std=c11` to provide the few additional error checks and also specify `c11` as the standard (you will get a few warnings about features added in `c99` if you use `-pedantic` and fail to specify either `c99` or `c11` as the standard). Good luck with your coding. Gtk is a great gui toolkit (there is a lot to it), so expect to spend time learning it (just like with any gui toolkit).

Comment: Another bonus is using MinGW and the pre-built gtk+ libraries, your code will build the same way on Windows. I generally put all my pre-built binaries under the `c:\opt` directory, e.g. `c:\opt\gtk+2` and `c:\opt\gtk+3` (that just keeps all libraries and headers in one place on windows)

Comment: Yes I tried to use MinGW but it was not working. Now I use visual studio code on a Linux subsystem on windows for coding and build the project on raspberry pi. But it would be easier to code in windows and also do the first debugging on windows. So I will try it again because one of the reasons why I try to learn gtk+ is that is a cross-platform.

Comment: You have to install the Gtk+ libraries which you can generally find at [Gnome.org win32 Gtk binaries](https://download.gnome.org/binaries/win32/gtk+/). MinGW is the way to go building to run on windows. VS may be able to use WSL with a native Gtk+ install there -- though I have never tried. All the VS work I do is from the command line in the *VS Developer's Command Prompt* calling `cl.exe` directly (I can build 20 packages in the time it takes to setup one project in the VS IDE)

Answer (score 0):

I will extend a little bit this part where @David C. Rankin said:

```
(void)wid;      /* cast to void to avoid unused var warning */
(void)event;
```

Because there is something important which a lot o people does not know about it.

The need of cast is all most all the time wrong used, and this happens because there is another function which is called:

```
g_signal_connect_swapped()
```

Which is there to avoid the need of so many casts by swapping the fist parameter with the last one.

Lets take the following example:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

GtkWidget *createWindow ( const gint width, const gint height );
void user_function      ( GtkWidget *object, gpointer   user_data );

int main ( void )
{
    GtkWidget *window;
    gtk_init ( NULL, NULL );
    /// ***
    window = createWindow( 300, 300 );
    /// ***
    g_signal_connect ( window, "destroy",       G_CALLBACK( user_function ),  NULL );
    /// ***
    gtk_widget_show_all ( window );
    gtk_main();
}

GtkWidget *createWindow ( const gint width, const gint height )
{
    GtkWidget *window = gtk_window_new  ( GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL );
    gtk_widget_set_size_request ( window, width, height );
    gtk_container_set_border_width ( GTK_CONTAINER ( window ), 50 );
    return window;
}

void user_function ( GtkWidget *object, gpointer   user_data )
{
    (void)object;
    (void)user_data;
    g_print( "Goodbye\n" );
    gtk_main_quit();
}
```

Here as you can see the callback function signature looks like this:

`void user_function ( GtkWidget *object, gpointer   user_data )`

Now there are two casts needed in this case, but we can drop one (gpointer data for example) of them by calling `g_signal_connect_swapped` like this:

```
g_signal_connect_swapped ( window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK( user_function ),  NULL
```

or even better:

```
g_signal_connect_swapped ( window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK( user_function ),  (gpointer)"Goodbye" );
```

Now our program looks like this:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

GtkWidget *createWindow ( const gint width, const gint height );
void user_function      ( gpointer data );

int main ( void )
{
    GtkWidget *window;
    gtk_init ( NULL, NULL );
    /// ***
    window = createWindow( 300, 300 );
    /// ***
    g_signal_connect_swapped ( window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK( user_function ),  (gpointer)"Goodbye" );
    /// ***
    gtk_widget_show_all ( window );
    gtk_main();
}

GtkWidget *createWindow ( const gint width, const gint height )
{
    GtkWidget *window = gtk_window_new  ( GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL );
    gtk_widget_set_size_request ( window, width, height );
    gtk_container_set_border_width ( GTK_CONTAINER ( window ), 50 );
    return window;
}

void user_function ( gpointer data )
{
    g_print( "%s\n", (char*)data );
    gtk_main_quit();
}
```

And there are no CASTs anymore.

Here is a better Example:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

gboolean scroll_callback    ( GtkWidget *widget, GdkEvent  *event );
gboolean show_mouse_pressed ( GtkWidget *widget, GdkEventButton *event );

int main ( void )
{
    GtkWidget *window;
    GtkWidget *button;
    gtk_init( NULL, NULL );
    /// ***
    window = gtk_window_new( GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL );
    gtk_window_set_default_size( GTK_WINDOW( window ), 300, 250 );
    g_signal_connect( window, "destroy", gtk_main_quit, NULL );
    gtk_container_set_border_width( GTK_CONTAINER( window ), 50 );
    /// ***
    button = gtk_button_new_with_mnemonic( "_Click me" );

    gtk_widget_add_events( button, GDK_BUTTON_PRESS );
    gtk_widget_add_events( button, GDK_SCROLL_MASK );

    ///g_signal_connect( button, "clicked", gtk_main_quit, NULL );
    gtk_container_add( GTK_CONTAINER( window ), button );
    /// ***
    g_signal_connect_swapped( button, "button_press_event", G_CALLBACK( show_mouse_pressed ), window );
    g_signal_connect_swapped( button, "scroll_event", G_CALLBACK( scroll_callback ), window );
    /// ***
    gtk_widget_show_all( window );
    gtk_main();
}

gboolean scroll_callback ( GtkWidget *widget, GdkEvent  *event )
{
    if ( event->type == GDK_SCROLL ) /// Scroll was Catched ?
    {
        if ( event->scroll.direction == GDK_SCROLL_DOWN ) /// It is down?
        {
            g_print( "Scroll-Down Detected\n" );
            gtk_window_set_title( GTK_WINDOW( widget ), "Scroll-Down Detected" );
        }

        if ( event->scroll.direction == GDK_SCROLL_UP ) /// It is up?
        {
            g_print( "Scroll-UP Detected\n" );
            gtk_window_set_title( GTK_WINDOW( widget ), "Scroll-UP Detected" );
        }
        return FALSE;
    }
    return TRUE;
}

gboolean show_mouse_pressed ( GtkWidget *widget, GdkEventButton *event )
{
    assert ( widget != NULL );
    if ( gtk_widget_get_has_window ( widget ) )
    {
        if ( event->type == GDK_BUTTON_PRESS )
        {
            g_print( "The mouse clicked the button\n" );
            gtk_window_set_title( GTK_WINDOW( widget ),  "The mouse was Clicked" );
        }
        return TRUE;
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```